# How to show a class in CodeIgniter so that I can retrive data

Tags: codeigniter

In controllers\home.php there is a class called `home` and function called `index`. And right there I have `$data['users'] = $this->users->table();`

And there is `Class Users extends CI_Model` within `models\users.php`.

But CodeIgniter says that `Call to a member function table() on a non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\HCAWebApp\application\controllers\home.php` on line 22 aka where the `$data['users'] = $this->users->table();` line is located.

What is wrong with my code? I think it cannot locate the users.php.

Comment: did you load the users model?

Comment: did you load the model prior to calling `$this->users` via `$this->load->model('users')` ?

Comment: @tomexsans, I think I did not.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter, it worked when I used the `load`. Thank you all. Why not post it as answer so I can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the model prior to calling `$this->users` via `$this->load->model('users')`.

Answer (score 1):

looking at the error YOU have or did not load the model, load it first like

`$this->load->model('users');`

OTHERS ..

or if you have a lot of models to load use an array like

`$this->load->model(array('users','model1','model2'));`

if you like to load it automatically just open `config/autoload.php`

`$autoload['model'] = array('users');`

then you can use it now as `$data['users'] = $this->users->table();`

You could also assign a different name to the model like:

`$this->load->model('users','foobar');`

then use it as `$data['users'] = $this->foobar->table();`